# Is there a way to get the IP address of a client virtual machine in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13, pgbouncer

I can get the IP address if the Postgres connection is done from the 5432 port.
Now If I connect Postgres with 6432 port means the connection comes from pgbouncer at this time I'm not getting the IP address of the machine getting localhost in the Client IP address tab from **pg_stat_activity** and in logs also getting the same localhost.
I have enabled **log_hostname** and **log_line_prefix** also I have added **%h and %r** to get the IP of the machine from which the connection happed.
My purpose is to audit/to get the address for which query or action happened from which machine

Comment: I doubt you can achieve that. The only IP address that the Postgres server sees is the one from the server where pgBouncer is running. The only thing you could do is to make that information available in `application_name`: https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html#application_name_add_host

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I got IP in Postgres logs by enabling application_name_add_host in pgbouncer and app name added in log_line_prefix in postgresql.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got IP in Postgres logs by enabling application_name_add_host in pgbouncer and app name added in log_line_prefix in postgresql.conf